# calling next on observer a second time doesn't seem to work

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to simulate a wait moment where the user has to wait for a (currently simulated) backend call. When the wait moment appears, I want the buttons to be disabled and a message to be shown. I try to achieve this with the following code.

When a button is clicked, this piece of code is executed in a service:

```
//Simulate waiting for backend
this.calculatingObserver.next(true);
console.log("disabled");
await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)));
this.calculatingObserver.next(false);
console.log("enabled");
```

This is executed as I see the console logs appear.

This is the signature of the observer:

```
private calculatingObserver: Observer<boolean> = null;
```

And this is how I retrieve an observable for it:

```
public get Calculating$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable((calculatingObserver: Observer<boolean>) => {
        this.calculatingObserver = calculatingObserver;
    });
}
```

In my component, I port this observable to a new property

```
//In the component class
Calculating$: Observable<boolean>;

//in ngOnInit
this.Calculating$ = this._calculateService.Calculating$;
```

And in the html of the compoennt I use the property like this for testing:

```
Calculating: {{Calculating$ | async}}
```

When I test the code, initialy the calculating is not set (empty string). When I click the button, I see the Calculating changing to true. But then, it never changes to false. So as it seems, something goes wrong during the execution of

```
this.calculatingObserver.next(false);
```

and I cannot figure out why. What am I doing wrong here and why isn't the Calculating changing to false?

The timeout is working as it takes 2 seconds before the enabled is printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a stackblitz and changed the code in your service to this:

`this.calculatingObserver.next(true);
    console.log("disabled");
    setTimeout(() => {this.calculatingObserver.next(false);console.log("enabled");}, 2000);`

and it does seem to work that way: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2afnv9

Comment: So there is no way to use async and await to pause a few seconds as simulation for waiting for an api call?

Comment: It works just as well with `await`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkgj7e?file=src/app/service.service.ts